# Cannot delete cookie (java web)

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, session-cookies

I'm having an issue with deleting cookies

MemberArea.jsp

```
<%
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies != null)
{
    for(Cookie cookie: cookies)
    {
        if(cookie.getName().equals("username"))
            username = cookie.getValue();
        else if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID"))
            sessionID = cookie.getValue();          
    }
}
if(username == null || sessionID == null)
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
%>
Username: <%=username %> <br>
Current Session: <%=sessionID %>

<form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/MemberAreaController" 
 method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="destroy">
    <input type="Submit" value="Logout">
</form>
</body>
```

The following code(MemberController.java) is triggered from MemberArea.jsp

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
System.out.println(cookies);
for(Cookie cookie: cookies)
{       
    System.out.println(cookie.getName());
    System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
    cookie.setValue(null);
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
} 
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

After click logout button and back to MemberArea.jsp, the user still login.